# Combining the data from 2 lists

Tags: python, list

I am new to programming. I have 2 list I want to grab one element from title and one element from price and save it in a file meal.txt
**Title**

```
['Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie', 'McFizz Guava', 'Date Pie', 'Spicy McCrispy Deluxe - Regular Meal', 'McChicken - Regular Meal', 'Curly Fries', 'Salted Caramel Shake']
```

**Price:**

```
['Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 159', 'Rs 195', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 239', 'Rs 239']
```

Desired output:
**in meal.txt file**

```
Title : Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288
#space
Title : Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288 
....
```

Like grab one element on index(0) of Title and combine it with index(0) of price

Comment: Look into [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zip and append strings.  join into one string

```
data1 = ['Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie', 'McFizz Guava', 'Date Pie', 'Spicy McCrispy Deluxe - Regular Meal', 'McChicken - Regular Meal', 'Curly Fries', 'Salted Caramel Shake']
data2 = ['Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 159', 'Rs 195', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 239', 'Rs 239']
newtxt = '\n'.join([f'{i+1}.Title : {title}\nPrice : {price}\n' for i, title, price in zip(range(len(data1)),data1,data2)])
```

Comment: How would I write the output to a file deals.txt?

Comment: `open("deals.txt","w").write(newtxt)` should do it

Comment: How to add number to the content like `1.Title : Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288`              `2.Title : Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288 `

Comment: zip a range in and add it into the interpolation

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: added it, you can just create a new question next time

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to combine two lists is `zip`.

```
for title, price in zip(titles, prices):
   print(f'Title : {title}\nPrice : {price}\n')
```

Comment: `Title : ['McArabia with Drink', 'Grand Chicken Spicy with Drink', 'Deal for 2', 'Deal for 4', 'Big Mac + Regular Drink']
Price : Rs 398` The title is getting printed as a list

Comment: Check your values.  Perhaps you wrote `{titles}`, or made `titles` a list of lists

Comment: How to add number to the content like `1.Title : Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288`              `2.Title : Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288 `

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
with open("meal.txt", "w") as file:
    for e in range(len(title)):
        file.write("%s.Title : %s\nPrice : %s\n" % (str(e+1), title[e], price[e]))
```

Comment: How to add number to the content like `1.Title : Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288`              `2.Title : Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288 `

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function is particularly useful. Also using `.format()` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)) and [writing out to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in python will be important.

```
l1 = ['Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie', 'McFizz Guava', 'Date Pie', 'Spicy McCrispy Deluxe - Regular Meal', 'McChicken - Regular Meal', 'Curly Fries', 'Salted Caramel Shake']
l2 = ['Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 159', 'Rs 195', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 239', 'Rs 239']

outstring = ''
for elem1, elem2 in zip(l1, l2):
    s = 'Title : {}\nPrice : {}\n\n'.format(elem1, elem2)
    outstring += s

fn = 'meal.txt'
with open(fn, 'w') as f:
    f.write(outstring)
```

Comment: How to add number to the content like `1.Title : Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288`              `2.Title : Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288 `

Answer (score 0):

```
Title = ['Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Cappuccino with Double, Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie', 'Latte with Double', 'Chocolate Cookie', 'McFizz Guava', 'Date Pie', 'Spicy McCrispy Deluxe - Regular Meal', 'McChicken - Regular Meal', 'Curly Fries', 'Salted Caramel Shake']

Price = ['Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 288', 'Rs 159', 'Rs 195', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 416', 'Rs 239', 'Rs 239']

data_dict = dict(zip(Title, Price))  

for title, price in data_dict.items():  
    print("Title : {}\nPrice : {}\n".format(title, price))
```

Comment: How to add number to the content like `1.Title : Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288`              `2.Title : Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Price : Rs 288 `

Comment: Hi! You can do it by adding the `enumerate`  function:
`data_dict = dict(zip(Title, Price))`   
`for i, data_dict_items in enumerate(data_dict.items()):`   
      `Title, Price = data_dict_items` 
      `print("{}.Title : {}\nPrice : {}\n".format(i, Title, Price))`

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're looking for is the zip() function.

Untested:

```
for name, price in zip(names, prices):
    print("Product: %s\nPrice: %0.2f/n" % (name, price))
```

Comment: I've no idea; I got one too. I suspect it was before I added the example. I'm relatively new to adding answers to stack overflow myself. It was IMO a valid question, with a Python specific answer, that isn't necessarily easy to find without the keyword zip to search for.